# Updating only changed values into MongoDB from a Form Submission

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, httprequest, insert-update

I've been setting up a **REST API** in the **Play Framework** (*2.6*) in **Scala** and been trying to implement the use of a (**Scala**) **Form** but I'm having some difficulties when attempting to find the best practice for updating only values that have changed upon form submission. I have used this [article as a reference](https://justinrodenbostel.com/2016/01/27/building-a-simple-rest-api-with-scala-play-part-2/) (as well as others) and it uses the *HTTP Request* `PATCH` shown as something similar to this with the *Routes* file:

```
   PATCH  /update/:collName    controllers.IndexC.update(collName: String, oId: Option[BSONObjectID])
```

However if I route to this in my (**Play**) template for the *form action* like this:

```
   @form(action = routes.IndexC.update(collName, oId), 'method -> "patch", ...)
```

Then it brings up an error that it cannot locate the file (trying to use a `GET`
request). I've read somewhere that this can happen if the browser doesn't support `PATCH` as a *HTTP Request*. Or perhaps I am completely misunderstanding this - we'll call that ***part 1 of my gap in knowledge***.

Also (***part 2 of my gap in knowledge***) I am struggling to understand how only the values from the form submission can be retrieved (rather than all input box values). So suppose that I had a very simple Scala model & form looking like this:

```
   case class Countries(countryName: String, countryCode: String, currencyCode: String)

   object Countries {

     val form = Form(
       mapping(
         "countryName" -> nonEmptyText,
         "countryCode" -> nonEmptyText,
         "currencyCode" -> nonEmptyText
       )(Countries.apply)(Countries.unapply)
     )

   }
```

Is there a way `bindFromRequest` can help to retrieve just those input values that have changed (from the **Mongo database collection** and those that were fed initially into the form - using `Countries.form.fill`). Or is this perhaps better done elsewhere with a more sensible approach? Or maybe ***part 1***'s solution makes this irrelevant. Many thanks.

Comment: Such form binding should not be award of the DB, in respect to MVC basics

Comment: @cchantep - I'm not absolutely sure what you mean (could be a typo) but if you meant to say: "Such form binding should not be **aware** of the DB" - then it's not. But of course this doesn't address the problem. Any insight is always welcome of course. Thanks

Comment: @cchantep - do you have any experience of updating only modified values from a scala form? I'm finding it increasingly difficult to get any answers in *Stack Overflow*. Perhaps there is better forum or place to share knowledge (particular to Play Framework/Scala/Reactive Mongo). Suggestions welcome

Answer (score 0):

An object of type `Form` will always have something for each field in the form (or `None` of course if they are optional). The form tag on the page (and its inputs) determine which objects are included in the http post request. `bindFromRequest` will match up the html input field names with the fields in the Form case class (loosely speaking). So there is no automatic way to detect only changed fields. Interesting use case though.

Thinking out loud:

1. Make a version of the Form object that has all optional fields, and check in the `bindFromRequest` which ones have values. Use this info to construct an update to the DB containing only those fields. On the front end, only populate the inputs that are changed. You will probably need a visible input which is not part of the form, then your special optional input which is part of the form and therefore part of the POST.
2. Construct a new case class with boolean `hasChanged<Field1>`, `hasChanged<Field2>` type fields (or a `Seq` thereof) which the front end sets when changes are detected. The Form object would map to this new case class and in the `bindFromRequest` you can use the booleans to intelligently construct the only-changed fields that are going to the DB.
3. When the form is first loaded, use the controller to cache the unchanged copy of the case class data. In the `bindFromRequest`, compare this to the cached value and construct the list of changed fields.
4. Switch from using a form and `bindFromRequest` to using Ajax. On the front end construct the POST object to contain only the changed fields. In the controller, use a JSON reads where all the case class fields are Options (ReadNullable). The controller can then figure out which one are populated based on which ones are present in the JSON.